# identify touches on subclass of UIViews created programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, touches

I am creating an app with cards. In my mainViewController, I have this code:

```
CardView *cardView = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CardWidth, CardHeight)];
                    cardView.card = [player.closedCards cardAtIndex:t];
                    [self.cardContainerView addSubview:cardView];
                    [cardView animateDealingToBottomPlayer:player withIndex:t withDelay:delay];
                    delay += 0.1f;
```

where CardView is a subclass of UIView. Each Card is a unique cardView and in CardView.m I do have:

```
@implementation CardView
{
    UIImageView *_backImageView;
    UIImageView *_frontImageView;
    CGFloat _angle;
}

@synthesize card = _card;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self loadBack];
        self.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadBack
{
    if (_backImageView == nil)
    {
        _backImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        _backImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"];
        _backImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        [self addSubview:_backImageView];
    }
}
```

and the implementations for other functions .

Since in order to win space, one card is placed on top of the others (half of teh card is visible and the rest is covered by the next card and so on), I want to identify touches on each card.

If I place that code in CardView:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Card is touched");
}
```

it is never called. If I place it in the GameView Controller it is called anywhere that I will touch, but I do not know how to identify which cardView is called. Can you give me a hint?

**EDIT:**
I decided to use gestures. Therefore in my mainViewController changed the code to this:

```
for (PlayerPosition p = startingPlayer.position; p < startingPlayer.position + 4; ++p)
{
   CardView *cardView = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CardWidth, CardHeight)];
   cardView.card = [player.closedCards cardAtIndex:t];
   cardView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
   [self.cardContainerView addSubview:cardView];
   [cardView animateDealingToBottomPlayer:player withIndex:t withDelay:delay];
   delay += 0.1f;
   UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cardSelected:)];
   [cardView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```

but this is never called.

```
-(void)cardSelected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Card Selected with gestures");
}
```

Why is that?

**EDIT 2:**

I have also tried adding this:

```
self.cardContainerView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

or changing this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cardSelected:)];
```

to this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self .cardContainerView action:@selector(cardSelected:)];
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: Have you considered gesture recognisers?

Comment: @Wain I haven't used them before to be honest and I did not know how to implement. Do you think it is going to be easier?

Comment: This may not be the best way but you could get the x and y of the touch and if you have the frame of each card you can see which one was touched. I would recommend gesture recognisers.

Answer (score 1):

If you instead add a tap gesture recogniser to each card view you can get a callback to a method you specify and the gesture is connected to the view so you can directly get a reference to it.

---

Your `CardView` (which I guess is a subclass of `UIView`?) has 2 subviews, which are image views:

```
UIImageView *_backImageView;
UIImageView *_frontImageView;
```

You may want to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` on one or both of them (depending on when the card should be tappable and when the subviews are shown and hidden).

You can also act as the delegate of the gesture (if you need to, or just temporarily to debug that the gesture is getting triggered but blocked by something other gesture).

Comment: You have image views as subviews, these are probably blocking the touches as by default they disable `userInteractionEnabled`. You should be able to enable touches without side effects.

Comment: do you mean something different than this : cardView.userInteractionEnabled=YES; ? The above code happens inside a for loop if it makes any difference.

Comment: You are guessing right, it is a subclass of UIView. Should i leave the rest userInteractionEnables? now the code for the delegate is commented. I have added the userInteractionEnabled for the UIImageView but yet again nothing. Can you propose changes on my code because whatever combination I tried does not seem to work.

Comment: Ok, leave the target as self, comment the code for (all of) the image views for front and back (then you can tell if they are causing an issue). Just get touches on the card view working, then add each of the subviews one by one to find the blocker.

Comment: not working again. I will check it again from the beginning. target is self, userInteraction is enabled for every cardView in the for loop and every cardView is added as a subview in the cardContainerView (in which it makes no difference whether the userInteraction is enabled or not - this is a subclass of UIView as well).

Comment: Were the gesture delegate methods called?

Comment: hmm it is never called. I have no assignment for the recognizer.delegate. all the functions are in mainviewcontoller. what should i includ and where?

Comment: Set `mainviewcontoller` as the delegate, like it is the target, and implement the delegate methods, like you implement the action method.

Comment: What is the frame of these card views and the frame of the superview they're being added to?

Comment: for each cardView this is the frame : CardView *cardView = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CardWidth, CardHeight)]; where Cardwidth and cardheight are equal to 100. The parent View which is the cardContainerView is the whole screen (320*480). Notice that each card covers half of the card that is below  it (so only half of the card is visible).

Comment: Checked at runtime? Something is blocking the touches, that's usually another view, another gesture or the frame of a superview (being too small)